# Some call participants can't see shared screen

Tags: windows-10, skype

When having group calls and someone shares the screen, some of the members in the call are able to see it and others not. All have the Skype 8.64.0.83 and it's not the version from Microsoft Store.

The one's that are not able to see the shared screen are using Windows 10 computers and if they minimize Skype, then appears a tiny Skype square where it's possible to see the screen being shared.

I'm one of the persons that can't see the screen being shared. Yet, if I share mine, some people see and others don't.

Thought about changing for a different platform but if possible we're already using Skype and so wouldn't like to change.

What can be done to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to Skype version 8.64.0.88 solved the problem. To get the new version, download it [here](https://www.skype.com/en/get-skype/).